# using condition variable and unique_lock mechanisms to create a thread-safe fifo queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, fifo

consider this FIFO queue (`using namespace std`), which I created after reading alot on c++11 newer features.

```
void Fifoqueue::pop(int& item)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
    cv.wait(lock , [this]()//unlock mutex and wait here for notify_* sig
    { 
        return !q.empty(); //block until both notify_* sig is caught and the queue is not empty. 
    });//when we reach here the mutex is locked and execution continues

    item = q.front();
    q.pop();    
}

bool Fifoqueue::pop_try(int& item)
{   
    bool bHasNewData = false;
    unique_lock<mutex> ulock(mtx,defer_lock);//defer lock,so noblock        
    if ( ulock.try_lock() && !q.empty() )//q.empty() will only be checked on a successful locking
    {
        bHasNewData = true;
        item = q.front();
        q.pop();        
    }

    return bHasNewData;
}

void Fifoqueue::push(const int& item)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
    q.push( item );
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

where

```
queue< int , list<int> > q;
condition_variable cv;
mutex mtx;
```

Could you verify that I have understood the `unique_lock` , and `conditional_variables` correctly (according to my in line comments) in order to create a blocking and a non-blocking `pop` call to this queue? Is thread safety guaranteed?

Comment: Your title and your post body bear little resemblance to one another. Do you wish to know why we use these features, or do you wish for a review of your code?

Comment: @PreferenceBean you are correct, I started with a different question and changed it afterards. sorry about that. fixed now.

Comment: It is dependent from you intention, but `pop_try` normally returns false if queue is *empty*, not when it is failed to acquire lock. It could be implemented as `pop` method, but perform `if(q.empty()) return false;` instead of `wait`. Other code is just common using of locks and conditional variables (that  is, it is correct).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you. However, if implemented as you say, even pop_try will block (albeir for very little) if the mutex is locked somewhere else. right?

Comment: Yes, `pop_try` may be blocked on mutex, and it is OK (again, this is dependent from your intention). Take a look to your FIFO queue *outside*. This queue has notion about elements in it, but **the mutex is internal** for queue implementation.  Because of that, `if queue is empty then return false` has a sence, but `do not wait on mutex` -  hasn't.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. Agreed - I will change it (in my code)